# Error while coloring the table

Tags: color

I am trying to color the rows in the table. I used both `\cellcolor{blue!25}` and `\rowcolor` options.

The packages are included in the main file are given below...

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

but it shows the error as "Undefined control sequence".

can anybody tell how to solve my problem...

Comment: I retagged your question as there is no latex3 code involved and none of the packages are directly supported by the latex project.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to load `color` and `xcolor` (just `xcolor` if you want the `!` syntax) The table colour commands are defined in `colortbl` which you can load explicitly or, better in this case, by adding `[tables]` option to `xcolor`

Comment: i tried that.... but in result, no color is appearing in the table. i have a doubt whether my latex version is not supporting this package?

Comment: @RincyRaphael If the package is not available you would get an error saying the file was missing from the `\usepackage` line. It is not possible for anyone to say what is wrong with code if you do not show the code. Every question should include a small _complete_ document that demonstrates the problem, make a small document and include it in full above and show the exact error message you get (copied from the log file from `!` to `?`)